# what's wrong with this query? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "UPDATE site_ayarlar 
 SET site_baslik = '$_POST[site_baslik]',
  site_slogan = '$_POST[site_slogan]', 
  meta_desc = '$_POST[meta_desc]',
  meta_key = '$_POST[meta_key]',
  meta_auth = '$_POST[meta_auth]',
  meta_copy = '$_POST[meta_copy]', 
  meta_robots = '$_POST[meta_robots]' ";
```

And the error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

Nevermind, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Apart from being *extremely* vulnerable to injections, you seem to have forgotten the `WHERE` part in your query.

Comment: BTW: Did you `print_r($sql)` in order to see the query? A `'` in any of the `$_POST` vars *will* break the query.

Comment: Please use mysql_real_escape_string() to get at least some basic security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,

```
    $site_baslik = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['site_baslik']);
    $site_slogan = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['site_slogan']);
    $meta_desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meta_desc']);
    $meta_key = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meta_key']);
    $meta_auth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meta_auth']);
    $meta_copy = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meta_copy']);
    $meta_robots = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meta_robots']);

    $sql = "UPDATE site_ayarlar 
        SET site_baslik = '$site_baslik' ,
          site_slogan = '$site_slogan', 
          meta_desc = '$meta_desc',
          meta_key = '$meta_key',
          meta_auth = '$meta_auth',
          meta_copy = '$meta_copy', 
          meta_robots = '$meta_robots' 

        WHERE some_condition
    ";
```

and if you dont put some where condition, you will update all your db with the same data set

Answer (score 13):

Extra quote here:

```
'$_POST['meta_auth]'
```

And, of course:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST[key_name]` must be `".$_POST['key_name']."`

Comment: Not necessarily (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). At least not in this specific case. I *do* agree with you on this one, but it's a matter of preference. It seems to me that OP has more important things to worry about :)

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "UPDATE site_ayarlar SET site_baslik = '$_POST[site_baslik]', site_slogan = '$_POST[site_slogan]', meta_desc = '$_POST[meta_desc]', meta_key = '$_POST[meta_key]', meta_auth = '$_POST[meta_auth]', meta_copy = '$_POST[meta_copy]', meta_robots = '$_POST[meta_robots]' ";

Answer (score 0):

if you are using array variables inside a double-quoted string you need to enclose them in {} like this {$_POST['meta']}.

But as Jensgram pointed out, this approach is extremely vulnerable to injections.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. I never use $_POST enclosed in single quotes.